# Cookie is not set in Internet Explorer, gives an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

I have been using the below code, to create a cookie, this works completely fine in all the browsers except **INTERNET EXPLORER**.. it gives the below error when i click on create cookie button.

**Error**

```
Message: '$' is undefined
Line: 4
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/js/scripts.js
```

**Code**

```
<p>Click on the <strong>Set Cookie</strong> button below to create the testing cookie.</p><br>
            <button style="color: black" input type="button" onclick="set_cookie(<?php echo "'".$set_cookie_url."'" ?> );" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["cookieid"])) { ?> Disabled <?php } ?>value='Set Cookie'><b>Set cookie</b></button>
```

**JS Code**

```
function set_cookie(url){
    $.get( url, { cookieid: "628929", projectid: "1" }, set_cookie_complete);
    $('body').modal('show') ;
}
function set_cookie_complete(){
    location.reload();  
}

function unset_cookie(url){
    $.get( url, { cookieid: "628929", projectid: "1" }, unset_cookie_complete);
    $('body').modal('show') ;
}
function unset_cookie_complete(){
    location.reload();  
}
```

**can anybody help me to get rid of this error and set the cookie**

Comment: Just a note: use single quotes ( '\'' ) for strings and commas ( , ) in echo command, it will make your PHP code work faster ;)

Comment: ok, but what u have told has nothing to do with the problem above right?

Comment: yes, most probably. Your problem is in JS, not PHP. Does the jQuery library load correctly?

Comment: im quite new to jquery i used this link only to load the library 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: What IE do you use? jQuery 2.x does not support older versions! Try IE10 or IE11 (if possible). If not, you must use jquery 1.11.x

Comment: im using IE 8, if i want to use jquery 1.11.x... can u tell how to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69280/discussion-between-sho-gum-lew-and-radek-pech).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE8 and older you cannot use jQuery 2.x

Change your link to version 1.11.x. For such simple code you use there should be no differences.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: using '//' on the start of the URL helps browser to decide how to process it and allow to use both HTTP or HTTPS. Not using it may result in url "http://your.server.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/..."

Comment: one small thing.. theres another error saying "Object doesnt support this property or method".. do u have any idea what is about

Comment: When you open IE debugger (press F12), it should stop on the errors which will tell you what exact method is the problem. (If you use any other jQuery plugins, you may need to get older versions compatible with 1.x.)